# What is the role of South in Django?

Tags: django, django-south

I'm beginner in Django.

I come across South in some apps' documentation. And I wanted to know what is it.

> "South is a tool to provide consistent, easy-to-use and
>   database-agnostic migrations for Django applications."

I read about it but can't determine what it does exactly.

Comment: Probably reading a bit further into [South's documentation](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/whataremigrations.html) might shed some more light on its purpose.

Comment: South is used to manage database changes.  Imagine you put a site live, and then the client asks you to add an extra attribute to a model.  You need to change the live database to achieve this and south will help you to do that.  The documentation is absolutely top notch, so if you do need to make database changes don't be afraid to jump in.

Comment: Instead of learning about South, you might just want to start with the Django 1.7 beta, in which South has been entirely replaced by a built-in migrations system.

Comment: Actually I'm not learning South, I just come across the name more than once and want to feed my curiosity. However, your information is helpful. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

South helps to keep your databases in sync with your models. Django's "syncdb" function will only create tables, not modify.  Rather than modifying the tables by hand, south takes a snapshot of the models and creates/runs "migration" code to get the database up to (or back to) this model snapshot.

This is especially helpful when you're working on a team where each dev has a VM with their own DB or if you're moving from a QA database to a Production database.

Comment: OMG This tool is very important and interesting that I was expecting. However it works whit all db (MySql...) ? Should I work with it if I'm not sure about future db modifications ? It will affect the speed of website or something like that ? Thank you

Comment: If my website is running and want to modify Models structure can I install it ? or should I use it from the beginning ?

Comment: As you quoted in your question, it is database agnostic...meaning that the migrations that it creates will work on whatever db you've got your app hooked up to. South will have no impact on site speed as it only runs when you tell it to perform a migration.

Comment: you'll need to add south to your installed apps in settings.py and if you've already got models defined, you'll run "python manage.py schemamigration --initial" to get your starting spot. For model changes after that you'll use --auto.

Answer (score 2):

Prior to Django 1.7, there was no built-in way to do [migrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/migrations/) when you made a change that affected the structure of your database (e.g., changed around the fields on a model).

[South](http://south.aeracode.org/) is one of the most popular third-party tools to fill this gap. It can automatically detect such changes and write migrations for you, as well as giving you the toolset to write migrations by hand yourself for more complex cases.